# Order by multiple fields in list of entity

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, criteria-api

I have a list of survey answers. Each answer store in table as value with id reference to parent survey field and reference to person who answer. Parent field store title and type of question.
Can i with sql do sort by multiple fields?

The problem for me is that answer value for multiple fields store in one table in one column as text.

UPD: there is exapmle
Answers table:

| Value | Field | Person |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 1 | user1 |
| no | 2 | user1 |
| 41 | 1 | user2 |
| yes | 2 | user2 |
| 52 | 1 | user3 |
| yes | 2 | user3 |

In answer entity i store list of this rows (by this example every answer contains list of 2 elements - number and boolean). So i need to sort answers first by value for field1, then by value for field2

Comment: Of course you can; `ORDER BY col1, col2, col3`.

Comment: That is one column for all fields

Comment: 2 answers and a comment that all indicate folks don't understand what you're asking. Maybe you should edit the question, and show the actual data in your table. Make example data if you want. Let's say the survey has only 3 questions: "1. What is your name", "2. What is your favourite color" and "3. Are you an adult". Make up 2 example survey takers and show us the exact data you do have (`SELECT * FROM x` for every table in your design). Until then I'm voting-to-close this.

Answer (score 0):

From the example provided, all you would need is a simple "ORDER BY" clause as per the first comment. Multiple columns can be added to the order by separated by a comma.  The key for you will then be how you need to order the columns, to achieve the desired output.

If you want all answers for Field1 first, followed by all answers for Field 2, then "Field" should be the first column
eg: ORDER BY Field, Value, Person
If you want field 1 then field 2, but per person, then you would say:
ORDER BY Person, field, Value

You may need to try run it a few times in different sequence to ensure that you get the desired result.